# Why do these two JavaScript regular expression produce different results?

Tags: javascript, regex

First, I have:

```js
const regEx = /(?:\S+\s)?\S*text\S*(?:\s\S+)?/;
const fullText = "one two text three four";
console.log(fullText.match(regEx));
```

which results in

> [ 'two text three', index: 4, input: 'one two text three four' ]

Then I have:

```js
const regEx2 = new RegExp("(?:\S+\s)?\S*text\S*(?:\s\S+)?", "g");
const fullText2 = "one two text three four";
console.log(fullText2.match(regEx2));
```

which results in:

> [ 'text' ]

Using `new RegExp`, how do I get the same result as the first block of code?

Comment: Double escape the `\S` and `\s` while using `new RegExp`

Comment: Try double escaping the backslash in new RegExp

Comment: Because \ in a string is an escape character, where as it isn't in a `//`